# Fourier Transform of u(-2-t)

Tags: signal-processing

I'm trying to find the Fourier Transform of 
x(t) = u(-2-t)

[Here's what I've tried:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eXpu.jpg)

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that u(t) is the unit step function.

Comment: What is $u$ ? $\phantom{}$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Oh I forgot to mention it's the unit step function.

Comment: You are assuming that the Fourier transform of $u$ is a function, but it is a distribution, related with the Dirac $\delta$.

Comment: Are you allowed to use tables of Fourier transforms or do you need to actually evaluate the integral?

Comment: @tilper I'm allowed to use tables, I was just trying to solve it by actually solving the integral.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Oh I get it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

u(-2-t)= u(-(t+2)) . Then for u(t)=1/2*sign(t)+1/2 her fourier transform is 1/j2pif + delta(f)/2 .
Used theorem of delay for u(-(t+2)).